# An invitation or the invitation?

Tags: articles

Is it correct to say an invitation or the invitation? I want to say to my friend thank you for the invitation ( as we both now which invitation I’m about)

Comment: You would say thank you for the [kind, lovely, nice etc] invitation. Not 'an invitation'.

Answer (score 1):

> Thank you for the invitation.

You are referring to a specific invitation so should use the definite article - 'the'

If you were referring to your friend getting you one of many invitations then you would use the indefinite article - 'an'